# Magento 2 - Unable to Get Request Params in controller

Tags: controllers, magento-2.1.7, parameter

I am trying to get input data in the controller but controller not getting url params.

```
<?php

namespace Crud\Crudatfrontend\Controller\Result;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;

class Result extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

     /**
     * @var Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    protected $resultJsonFactory; 

    /**
     * @param Context     $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
        )
    {

        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory; 
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }


    public function execute()
    {
        var_dump($this->getRequest()->getParams());die("testing");
        //echo '<pre>';
        //print_r($this->getRequest('height')->getParams());exit;
        $height = $this->getRequest()->getParam('height');
        //$height = 5;
        $weight = $this->getRequest()->getParam('weight');
        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('Crud\Crudatfrontend\Block\Index')
                ->setTemplate('Crud_Crudatfrontend::result.phtml')
                ->setData('height',$height)
                ->setData('weight',$weight)
                ->toHtml();

        $result->setData($block);
        return $result;
    } 
}
```

Here is my phtml file

```
<div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-12 column">

            <form name="form_height" method="POST" id="form_height">
                    <input type="text" name="height" class="form-control input-md">
                    <input type="text" name="weight" class="form-control input-md">
                    <input type="submit" id="calculateTotalSubmit"  name="calculate-total-submit" value="Calculate Total">
                </div> 
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>


<script>
require(['jquery'],function(){
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        alert("hi")
        jQuery("#form_height").submit(function(){

            var heightValue = jQuery("input[name='height']").val();
            var weightValue = jQuery("input[name='weight']").val();

            var url = "<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl().'crud/result/result/' ?>";
            jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: {height:heightValue,weight:weightValue},
            //data: jQuery(this).serialize(),
            success: function(response){
               // alert(heightValue);
                console.log(response.output);
                window.location.href = url;
            }
        });

        return false;
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I am getting values in console.

Comment: you better use `\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have given demo extension link for you.
https://github.com/magento1993/ajaxphtml

Comment: Did you check this module? it's not working for me

Comment: Yes, this extension is created by me for learning purpose

Comment: which version have you tested on?

Comment: I am not able to redirect on cntrlphtml/index/post/ after clicking on calculate total button

Comment: it's ajax so it will not redirect if you want to redirect then you have to remove ajax

Comment: So after clicking on button, where am i supposed to get value?

Comment: I am not getting in console

Comment: You can check the response in the network tab

Comment: /app/code/Biren/Controllerphtml/Controller/Index/Post.php remove the echo exit code from this file

Comment: I am getting {"output":"hi "} in network tab as i've added <?php 

    echo $block->getHeightData();
    echo $block->getWeightData();
    echo "hi";
?> in result.phtml file

Comment: and yes, i've removed that code

Comment: It's working fine then, you are getting post parameters and phtml is also working fine.

Comment: I am not getting height and weight values

Comment: u want height and width in phtml or controller?

Comment: I am getting hi on cntrlphtml/index/index page. but I want height and weight values too

Comment: I want to display height and weight on cntrlphtml/index/index page

Comment: ok wait i m updating extension in git

Comment: plz copy paste the new code , changes in below files. /app/code/Biren/Controllerphtml/view/frontend/templates/result.phtml     and  /app/code/Biren/Controllerphtml/Controller/Index/Post.php

Comment: Thank you so much man, I've been struggling since yesterday.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92350/discussion-between-biren-patel-and-bhakti-thakkar).

Comment: Please don't post a single link post

Answer (score 2):

Try this using `\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http`

```
<?php

namespace Crud\Crudatfrontend\Controller\Result;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;

class Result extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    /**
     * @var Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @var JsonFactory 
     */
    protected $resultJsonFactory;

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * Result constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     * @param JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    )
    {

        $this->request = $request;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface|\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json|\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $height = $this->request->getParam('height'); // or $height = $this->request->getPost('height'); 

        $weight = $this->request->getParam('height'); // or $weight = $this->request->getPost('height'); 

        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('Crud\Crudatfrontend\Block\Index')
            ->setTemplate('Crud_Crudatfrontend::result.phtml')
            ->setData('height',$height)
            ->setData('weight',$weight)
            ->toHtml();

        $result->setData($block);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried but it is still not working